# Find the correlation coefficient of RV $X$, $Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, binomial-coefficients

A fair coin is thrown three times in a row. We denote $X$ and $Y$, the number of times we obtain heads and tails in these three throws respectively.

I'm trying to find the correlation coefficient of $p(X,Y)$.

I know that $p(X,Y) = \frac{cov(X,Y)}{\sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)}}$

we can quickly figure out that $X$ and $Y$ are binomially distributed and as such, the variance of $Bin(3, 0.5) = \frac{3}{4}$

So to simplify:
$$p(X,Y) = \frac{cov(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\frac{9}{16}}} = \frac{cov(X,Y)}{\frac{3}{4}} = \frac{4cov(X,Y)}{3}$$

Now I also know that the covariance $cov(x,y) = E[XY]-E[X]\cdot E[Y]$

Figuring $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$ is easy enough $n \cdot p = \frac{3}{2}$,
so

$cov(x,y) = E[XY]-\frac{9}{4}$

but I'm not sure how to go on about figuring $E[XY]$ out on this one. Would appreciate some help, thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you mean that $Y=3-X$? Or are they two independent three coin tosses?

Comment: @Patricio edited that part on my question, hope its clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E[XY]=E[X(3-X)]= 3 E[X] - E\left[X^2\right]$

By using formula for second moment of a binomial random variable,

$E[X^2] = n (n-1) p^2 + n p = \cfrac{6}{2^2} + \cfrac{3}{2} = 3$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you did. Why is $E[XY] = 3E[X] - E[X^2]$?

Comment: $Y = 3 - X$ (or $X = 3 - Y$) so $E[XY] = E[X \cdot (3-X)] = E[3X] - E[X^2]$

Comment: Why is $Y = 3 - X$?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are dependent. We have $3$ coin tosses and $X + Y = 3$.

Comment: see if this answer helps for your last question. there are a few more if you search. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849196/distribution-of-a-binomial-variable-squared